# Error OnFailedTorecieve in admob

Tags: android, admob

I am having a problem with Admob. When I run my application, instead of showing the ad, it says `'XML attribute missing "adsize"'`.  The log says OnFailedToRecieve ad request. I can't trace what's happening. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Hey Shree Dev, can you please upload your code ?

Comment: thanks arjun its actually the problem of sdk version.i tried a different version of sdk 4.0.4 instead of 4.1.1 now its working...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before version 4.1.0, you needed to define an `attrs.xml` yourself, and so the namespace for `ads` probably has your package name:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/<your_package_name>"
```

With v4.1.0 or later, the SDK is bundled with this attributes file, so the `ads` namespace should be:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

The 4.1.1 SDK would have worked If you had made that change.  FYI, version 4.3.1 is available now.  It is recommended to be on the latest version as it is more stable and better supported.  You can download it [here](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/download.html) and get some helpful tips on migrating to v4.3.1 [here](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/11/migrating-to-v431-of-admob-sdk-for.html).